# Issue in careers.stackoverflow.com - no links in the tags once the job is applied

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

[image]

Once the job is applied, I'm seeing the list of similar jobs in the same pop-up with the text followed by
"Your application has been submitted. Here are some similar listings you might be interested in:".

I could see the tags in each of the job like "jquery", "wordpress" etc,

those tags are having links and able to navigate with that in other pages, but not in this pop-up. Please fix the same.

Answer (score 1):

We pushed a fix that takes the user to a tag + geo search based on the job suggested. So for the first job in the screenshot, it would take them to a search result page with "iOS in Austin, TX" page.